# No datas getting value from each

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, each

I have the following code:

```js
function get() {
  var item = '<li class="is-loading">';
  
  $.getJSON(urlJson, function(data){
    $.each(data, function(k,v){
     item = v['title']; // What I need to return
      console.log(url); // See? Here there is the content
    });
  });
  
  console.log('Item: ' + item); // See? Nothing else here is being returned like before
  return item;
}
```

And the problem is: the return is empty. Inside of `each` it looks like the value is not goint to `title`. Any suggestion?

Comment: post your json file or some part of json

Comment: @AbdulAhmad it's something like: 
[
  {
    "title": "Title here"
  }
]

Comment: I'm not an expert in this, but did you try `$(data).each(function() {});`?

Comment: @AbdulAhmad The point is the data is completely irrelevant to the problem at hand.

Comment: @Nit I see, here's the jQuery page on the getJson function, you need to pass the "title" as a parameter to the function http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: and your getjson function should be `.getJSON`

Comment: Updated code and still not working: 

function get() { var url = '<li class="is-loading">'; $.getJSON(urlJson, function(data){ $.each(data, function(k,v){ url = v['title']; // What I need to return console.log(url); // See? Here there is the content }); }); console.log('URL: ' + url); // See? Nothing here is being returned like before return url; }

Answer (score -1):

Inside each loop, it is v['title'], not data['title']. 
Assuming the json data as

```
{"titles":[
    {"title":"title 1"},
    {"title":"title 2"},
    {"title":"title 3"}
]}
```

The following piece of code works

```
$.getJSON(jsonFile, function(data){
   $.each(data['titles'], function(k, v){
        title += v['title'];
   });
});
```

Comment: Updated code and still not working:

`function get() {
  var url = '<li class="is-loading">';
  
  $.getJSON(urlJson, function(data){
    $.each(data, function(k,v){
    url = v['title']; // What I need to return
      console.log(url); // See? Here there is the content
    });
  });
  
  console.log('URL: ' + url); // See? Nothing here is being returned like before
  return url;
}`

Comment: It is because, the return happening before to getJson. getJSON is asynchronous, better use $.ajax with async set to false

Comment: the return is `undefined`:

`
function get() {
  var item = '';
  item += myFunc();
  console.log(item);
  return item;
}
  
function myFunc() {
    $.ajax({
    async: false,
    success: function(data) {
     $.getJSON(jsonUrl, function(data){
        $.each(data, function(k, v){
          return v['title'];
        });
      });
   }
  });
}
`

Comment: var jsonUrl = 'myJson.json';
    var item = '';
    function myFunc() {
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            url: jsonUrl,
            type: 'get',
            success: function(data) {
                $.each($.parseJSON(data)['titles'], function(k, v){
                    item += v['title']; 
                });
            }
        });
        return item;
    }

    console.log(myFunc());

Comment: It works, but the the result goes to var item. I need to push the title value to some tag, so I need to each title goes to a tag. For example: on json that you gave as example there are 3 `title`, I need to show on HTML the following:
`<p>title 1</p>`
`<p>title 2</p>`
`<p>title 3</p>`.

How can I do this?

Comment: <div id="container"></div>

<script>
var jsonUrl = 'myJson.json';
function myFunc() {
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: jsonUrl,
        type: 'get',
        success: function(data) {
            $.each($.parseJSON(data)['titles'], function(k, v){
                $('#container').append("<p>" + v['title'] + "</p>");
            });
        }
    });
}
myFunc();
</script>